# render error, element type was invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, listitem, react-native-elements

> render error, element type was invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got :undefined. you likely forget to export your component.

after i used List and ListItem from react-native-elements i got this error.

```
import React ,{ useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View,SafeAreaView,StyleSheet,TextInput,
Button,Alert,Image,FlatList} from 'react-native';
import {List,ListItem} from 'react-native-elements';
import Api from '../../../server/routes/userApi'

const Users = () => {
  
  const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState([])
  let api=new Api()

 const fetchData=async()=>{
   const users=await api.getUsers()
   console.log("users ",users)
  setUsersData(users)
 }
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData()
  },[])
return (
  <List>
    <FlatList
    data={usersData}
    renderItem={({item})=>(
      <ListItem
        roundAvatar
        title={`${item.firstName}`}
      />
    )}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  />
  </List>
  )
}

export default Users;
```

Comment: and had you exported your component?

Comment: export default Users; ? this??

Comment: @underscore_d    the flastlist actualy works , when i added the <List> component and ListItem i got this error

Answer (score 0):

You are using [react-native-elements](https://reactnativeelements.com/) which does not provide a `List` component anymore since version 1.0.

This is mentioned in the official documentation.

> List component has been removed! List was just a regular React Native View with some small margin styles. It wasn't actually needed to use the ListItem component. Instead we recommend using the FlatList or SectionList components from React Native which function both as Views and also displaying items, pull to refresh and more.

Hence, the import statement

```js
import {List, ListItem} from 'react-native-elements'
```

does not work, since `List` does not exist.

Just replace your `List` component with a `View`, set the necessary margins or other styles as desired and remove the import of `List`. Since you are already using a `FlatList` and a `ListItem` this should work.